# can check and default constraint work together in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to do a check at the time of creating a table that if any field is 'undefined' then change it to blank space ' '.
Something like -

```
Create Table ( 

Id real Primary Key,
Name Text Check(*** if this field is 'undefined' then change it to  ' ' ****)
);
```

Comment: Do you want to create a `default value` for the field? Or do you want to convert the string 'undefined' to a space?

Comment: suppose at the time of insertion the value of the field is 'undefined' then i want to change it to a space. i want to create a check constraint for 'undefined' and if it is 'undefined' then change it to blank space

Comment: Then you will need to just create a good insert statement, that doesn't put '' or 'undefined' and it should message the user when it is

Comment: A check constraint does not convert one value to another; it rejects non-conformant values. You need a trigger. Just to be clear, I am taking you to mean, when the value equals the string "undefined"; if you mean the value is missing or NULL, please advise. See pratik garg's answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can create trigger for this task -

```
create trigger insert_table_name 
BEFORE INSERT on table_name
for each row
when new.text = 'undefined'
begin
new.text:= '';
end;
```

and in case you want to do some other task also you can perform in this trigger.